# GHC -fhpc code coverage on Windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to check code coverage for my tasty unit tests. I found a way to do it [in the GHC docs user guide for hpc](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/hpc.html). The problem is that `ghc -fhpc Myfile.hs` doesn't generate a `.hpc` subdirectory or any `.tix` file, as the documentation claims it to do. Subsequently, I cannot run `hpc report`.

What am I missing? Does this not work on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, removing all `*.hi` and `*.o` files, forcing the compiler to recompile, worked. I really think the compiler should've noticed the flag, and that some files were missing.

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11798